# If $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ are iid, for what values of $a$ are $aX_1+(1-a)X_2\bot aX_1-(1-a)X_2?$

Tags: normal-distribution, independence

If $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$ are iid, for what values of $a$ are $aX_1+(1-a)X_2 \bot aX_1-(1-a)X_2$?

I know that if $S=aX_1+(1-a)X_2$ and $T=aX_1-(1-a)X_2$, then $S\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,(a^2+(1-a)^2)\sigma^2)$ and $t\sim \mathcal{N}(-\mu,(a^2+(1-a)^2)\sigma^2)$, but I'm not sure how to find a.

Comment: You can use convolution to calculate the law of sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, $S$ and $T$ are independent iff $f_{S,T}(s, t) = f_S(s)f_T(t)$. In your case, since $(S,T)$ is multivariate normal r.v (can you see why?), then it is suffice to show that $S$ and $T$ are uncorrelated. Namely, $cov(S,T) = 0$,
\begin{align}
cov(S, T) &= cov(aX_1 + (1-a)X_2, aX_1 - (1-a)X_2)\\
&=a^2var(X_1) - a(1-a)cov(X_1, X_2) + a(1-a)cov(X_1, X_2) - (1-a)^2var(X_2)\\
& = a^2\sigma^2 - (1-a)^2\sigma^2\\
& = \sigma^2(-1 + 2a) = 0 \to a=1/2  
\end{align}

Comment: Could you remind me how to derive the joint distribution here. I'm drawing blank.

Comment: @damned-to-suffer I've edited the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Ah, I see now. I was pretty close, but I didn't see the connection between S and T individually being normal, so (S,T) being MVN. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Corrected